# How to get value attirbute value from php 2d session variable

Tags: php, arrays, session

I am having an php session array like

```
["cart"]["123"] = "Biscuit"
["cart"]["124"] = "Jam"
```

If I want to access the 2nd element I will access `array_values($_SESSION["cart"])[$i]`
where $i runs in for loop. If I want to get the values `"123"` and `"124"`, how can i achieve it in a for loop with only `"cart"` and `$i`..?

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $key => $value)

{
  echo $key; // your 123 or 124 key
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an associative array easiest and best way is foreach because have to deal with key-value pairs rather than indexes(numbers).

```
foreach($arr['cart'] as $key => $val){
  echo "$key<br/>";
}
```

*I used a variable to hold values(`$arr`)*

But you can try for loop also:

```
$keys = array_keys($arr['cart']);
for ($keyindex = 0; $keyindex < count($keys); $keyindex++) {
    $key = $keys[$keyindex];
    echo $key."<br>";

}
```